# Xcode 7 is out. What about submission with Xcode 6 and swift 1.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have an application in review and it has been implemented with swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.x. In case Apple rejects my build I've to do the required fixes and submit it again. I've started working on the port to swift 2 but some of the libraries that I use have not been updated or they have dropped support for iOS 7 updating to swift 2.0... bad situation. That said, probably it takes some days (hopefully)  to get back to a completely working project.

**1)** in the meanwhile can I still compile my current code with Xcode 6 swift/1.2 ? does Apple accept this kind of submission or they requires a build created with Xcode 7.

**2)** Can I avoid switching to swift 2.0 and use anyway XCode 7?

Comment: 1. rmaddy answered this point. 2. No you can't, Xcode 7 = Swift 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use Xcode 6 and Swift 1.2. Apple will eventually require the newer tools but the now older one is still fine.

Of course you can't take advantage of any iOS 9 features this way  but at least make sure your app works under iOS 9.

Comment: what do you mean exactly with "Apple will eventually require the newer tool" . you mean in a couple of months?

Comment: I don't know when but every year Apple drops support for older versions of Xcode. It also starts requiring apps to support specific, newer versions of iOS, etc. so yes, eventually, several months from now, Apple will require Xcode 7 which means Swift 2. Put out your app now with Xcode 6 then take your time to upgrade so you are ready.